# Call derived class method from it's base abstract class using the methods string name

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, invoke

I am trying to have a dynamic approach to being able to call methods derived classes. 
I have 2 classes
The first class is a base class which has a method that will allow me to call methods by name.

```
public abstract class Main(){
     public void DoCall (string methodName){
        Type thisType = this.GetType();
        MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(methodName);
        theMethod.Invoke(this, null);
     }
}
```

The second is a derived class that has a method which I would like to call

```
public abstract class DoSomething(){
     public void Print(){
        Console.info("HELLO WORLD")
     }
}
```

In the end, I would like to call Print(), using the DoCall() method, because I will receive an object of type DoSomething(), but I can only cast it to Main();

```
public void ActOnIt(object Obj){
   Main received = (Main)Obj; 
   received.DoCall("Print");
}
```

I want to say its possible but maybe I don't have the right approach. Currently, I don't have exceptions but I also don't see Console print.

Comment: As fancy as "reflection-based" calls can be, they have a huge impact in your execution cost. 
From my own experience, every single time I've had the "need" to use reflection in C#, I ended up being better off implementing a "Proxy" class of some form.

Comment: Looking into this solution, however, you still need an interface to allow all the derived classes to have a standard. The problem is that when I receive these derived classes, each will be unique and have its own functions. I want to allow the client to have access to these functions by name.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing things is probably not the right design. Still, It should work technically.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ActOnIt(new DoSomething());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void ActOnIt(object Obj)
    {
        Main received = (Main)Obj;
        received.DoCall("Print");
    }
}

public class DoSomething:Main
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD");
    }
}

public abstract class Main
{
    public void DoCall(string methodName)
    {
        Type thisType = this.GetType();
        MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(methodName);
        theMethod.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What points make this a bad design? I can see that using reflection is expensive, and calling a derived class method is messy. However, ActOnIt() has to be generic enough to load any Main() Derived class, and allow to call its methods. Do you have other suggestions?